# JQueryUI Dialog Size

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I'm new to JQueryUI, and though I have a dialog working, it doesn't open at the size I think I'm specifying.  Why does setting the width and height when the dialog is defined not affect the initial size of the dialog?  How do I make it 600px by 500 px?

Here is the div that defines the dialog:

```
<div id="dialog-form" title="Create Appointment">   
  <form> . . . </form>
</div>
```

Here is the JavaScript that makes a dialog of it:

```
$(function() {
    $("#dialog-form").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        maxWidth:600,
        maxHeight: 500,
        width: 600,
        height: 500,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Create": function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            },
            Cancel: function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        },
        close: function() {
        }
    });
```

And the JavaScript that defines the button to open it:

```
$("#create-appt")
    .button()
    .click(function() {
        $("#dialog-form").dialog("open");
    });
});
```

---

Edit:

I see the problem now: this would have worked fine, except I was running it in Google Chrome using the `--app=...` command-line option, so it was not reloading the whole application.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Question: Why does setting the width and height when the dialog is defined not affect the initial size of the dialog?

Answer: It does...     what browser are you using and version of jQuery.

I cut/pasted your code from above into a small sample and it worked perfectly... I pasted the full sample below you can try it on your end.

```
 <html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
        <title>jQuery UI Example Page</title>
        <link type="text/css" href="css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.11.custom.css"      rel="stylesheet" />  
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.11.custom.min.js">     </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(function() {
            $("#dialog-form").dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                    maxWidth:600,
                    maxHeight: 500,
                    width: 600,
                    height: 500,
                    modal: true,
                    buttons: {
                    "Create": function() {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                    },
                    Cancel: function() {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                },
                    close: function() {
                }
                });
            });

            $("#create-appt")
            .button()
            .click(function() {
                $("#dialog-form").dialog("open");
            });
        });
        </script>

    </head>
        <body>
    <h1>test</h1>
    <div id="dialog-form" title="Create Appointment">   
        <p> this is my test </p>
    </div>
    <input type="button" id="create-appt" value="test"/>
    </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Just so: it was working.  See my edit above for the reason I couldn't see it.

Answer (score 15):

I don't know exactly what it's happening, but you can change a little bit your code and it'll produce the result you expect:

Instead of use autoOpen you can set these options on the onclick event:

```
$("#create-appt")
    .button()
    .click(function() {
        $("#dialog-form").dialog({width: 600,height:500});
    });
```

I hope this helps
best regards,
Marcelo Vismari

Comment: I tried it that way earlier, and it did the same thing; see my latest edit for the reason.