# How to implement pop up window with no status bar and address bar in HTML?

Tags: html, popup

I am trying to implement popup window in web application, i found following resource very useful

http://www.scriptfx.com/windows/plain/simple.htm#7

[image]

but all the examples shown here having following

menubar/toolbar and address location. 
In my html, i am calling high-chart to plot data points.

**Structure of html**

```
<html>
<body>
adding high chart plot by using div id. 
<script>
script for plotting plot using high chart
</script>
</body>
```

I really don't don't need html only. I can simply do the same in popup window.
How can i generate a pop up window without such bars i.e. a plain html with option for closing window on clicking a button or cross on it.

Comment: do you want the popup window to get content from a URL or from html div ?

Comment: i want to read html from local file.Currently using URL in my code ( I am newbie to web development) if there is another method using div i can use that also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change the design of the Browser popup window, from your comment you just want to popup a simple html code so there is a lot of easy to use custom modals (popups) built using javascript.

try one of these (just a simple search for `jquery modal window` and you will find a lot)

- [Simple Modal](http://simplemodal.plasm.it/#examples)
- [jQuery UI dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/)
- [Thick Box](http://codylindley.com/thickbox/)
- [Bootstrap Modal](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals)

### Edit

you can show your dialog this way ( jQuery UI )

```
    <div id="popup" title="Basic dialog" style="display:none;">
        <p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information.</p>
    </div> 

    <!-- button to show -->
    <a href="javascript::void()" class="showModal">Click to Show</a>
```

javascript

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    // show dialog on click
     $('.showModal').click(function(){
          $('#popup').dialog({width: 600,height: 600});
      });
    });
```

Comment: i have edited my question, JQuery UI dialog is quite useful but it has fixed dimension. If i increase dimension, there appears scroll bar. How can i avoid scroll bar.

Comment: @user15662 not it doesn't have a fixed dimension you can change the width and height just change the configuration see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5625835/jqueryui-dialog-size#answer-5626486

Comment: @user15662 you can do this `$('yourelement').dialog({width: 600,height: 600});`

Comment: Thanks it works! But how can i use this dialog box on clicking a text.

Comment: I have used the same tags but onclick there is no ouput. I have uploaded the same http://www.filedropper.com/output_3 here. can you pls check where am i wrong?

Comment: @user15662 put your code in js fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ click save and give me the result

Answer (score 1):

You cannot set window properties in HTML at all. All you can do in HTML to create popup windows is to use the `target="_blank"` attribute, but it only suggests that a link be opened in a new browsing context, which might be a new window, but these days it is more often a new tab.

What you are referring to is JavaScript code, not HTML. There are many resources, including SO questions and answers, on opening windows that way, as well on reasons for not doing so and using more advanced methods like modal dialogues.